# Вытащить значения из базы данных в Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, sql

Здравствуйте.
Задался внезапно вопросом: можно ли в C#-приложении без использования ORM выполнить SQL `SELECT` (налажено подключение к БД MS SQL) таким образом, чтобы вытаскивать значения в `Dictionary`, где ключом для каждого значения будет служить название его поля БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите [Работа с подключенным уровнем ADO .NET в C#](http://www.cyberforum.ru/ado-net/thread182279.html)